# Is it necessary to declare tags in facelet taglib 2.0?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, taglib

I've read the tutorial: http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/custom-component-library/ in which the authors are making empty `.taglib.xml` file, and according to tutorial the tags should be automatically loaded from the resource subfolder.

However, by me I have exception:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Could not get component metadata for
>   myComponent.xhtml

I have to manually specify each tag:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>myComponent</tag-name>
    <source>tags/mylib/myComponent.xhtml</source>
</tag>
```

Am I missing something? Where the tag definition locations would be automatically resolved? I'm running on **WebSphere 7.0** and **MyFaces 2.0.7**.

Comment: But they have taglib.xml file in project, this is how I googled them...

Comment: Post your code: declaration, definition, usage.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mix things up here. In my above mentioned blog post I added composite components to the tag lib like this:

```
<facelet-taglib>
  <namespace>http://jsflive.at/taglib</namespace>
  <composite-library-name>jsflive</composite-library-name>
</facelet-taglib>
```

This adds all composite components of the resource library with the name specified in `composite-library-name`. The tag names are derived from the file names by convention.

You on the contrary specify a tag for a Facelets fragment:

```
<tag>
  <tag-name>myComponent</tag-name>
  <source>tags/mylib/myComponent.xhtml</source>
</tag>
```

This has nothing to do with composite components! This approach is the pre JSF 2.0 way of defining custom tags for Facelets fragments. Your code creates a tag for the referenced xhtml file, which could be an arbitrary Facelets file. The path is relative to the location of the `taglib.xml` file in this case.

JSF 2.2 however will provide a way to specify tags for specific composite components. My post http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/04/06/jsf22-cc-taglib/ shows how this works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 2.2 way of specifying custom composites tags!